# How can I combine two functions into one (Symfony 4)?

Tags: php, function, symfony, controller, return

I am trying to combine this function...

```
public function index()
    {
      return $this->render('pages/index.html.twig', ['controller_name' => 'PagesController',]);
    }
```

...with this function:

```
public function index()
{
  $pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAll();
    return $this->render('pages/index.html.twig', array('pages' => $pages));
}
```

This is my approach:

```
public function index()
{
    $pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAll();
    return $this->render('pages/index.html.twig', array('pages' => $pages),['controller_name' => 'PagesController',]);
}
```

But I get just an error message:

> Argument 3 passed to
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::render() must be
>   an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response or null,
>   array given, called in
>   /Users/work/project/src/Controller/PagesController.php on line 18

Comment: You have made 2 parameter by mistake try `['pages' => $pages,'controller_name' => 'PagesController',]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing a third argument, you should be combining all the data that you want to pass to the view into one array.

```
public function index()
{
    $pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAll();
    return $this->render('pages/index.html.twig', array('pages' => $pages, 'controller_name' => 'PagesController'));
}
```

Comment: @Jarla BTW it's better to inject your repository into controller instead of getting it like you do. It's easier to mock it if needed